# Coverage a file with python -bb (bytes_warning=2)

Tags: python, testing, python-3.x, code-coverage, coverage.py

I use coverage to run tests and I would like to issue errors about str(bytes_instance), str(bytearray_instance) and comparing bytes/bytearray with str. (i.e. running `python -bb`). Is there a way to run coverage like this or to activate bytes_warning progamatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting, I had never seen `-bb` before, and it's too bad Python doesn't provide an environment variable that also controls it.

You can run coverage as a module, which lets you access the Python command line you want:

```
$ python -bb -m coverage run my_program.py
```

I think this will do the right thing for you.

Comment: `-m`, of course!  `-bb` is great when dealing with Python 2/3 codebases. You can just query its state via the `sys.flags` but not change it AFAIK.

Comment: A small comment, it does not work with Python 2.6 due to a bug in Python.

Comment: @Hernan: can you provide details?  Email is fine.